# event.preventDefault() on link with target="_top"

Tags: jquery

I have link that added from ajax with target="_top".

I want to cancel the redirect.

Html:

```
<ul id="controllerNav">
   <li>
       <a href="https://www.yacht.de/mein_dk/login.html" target="_top" title="Login">Login</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#controllerNav a').live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

**Now, the function occurs ,but after it finish the operation of the link also occurs also the "return false" and the other lines.**

Comment: what is happening now? if you want to be specific then you can `$('#controllerNav a[target="_top"]')`

Comment: this should work. and you dont need all those 3 lines. return false; is enough

Comment: This code works. Check jQuery version (live() is obsolete)

Comment: live was deprecated in 1.7, removed in 1.9

Answer (score 4):

Add **onclick** in HTML part and stop redirect

```
<ul id="controllerNav">
   <li>
       <a href="https://www.yacht.de/mein_dk/login.html" target="_top" title="Login" onclick="return false;">Login</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that's another solution. not an answer.

Comment: I have no the access to the html ot the callback of the ajax, just to add javascript.

Answer (score 1):

@FredericHamidi commented on a previous version of this answer, saying that delegated event handlers can't be cancelled primarily because, by nature of how jQuery's delegated events work, the click event would have been evaluated on the `<a>` by the time the delegated handler is fired off (hence, the time to cancel the redirect has passed).

You mention in your problem that your `<a>` is loaded via AJAX. At this point, the best solution just may be to add a direct event handler to your `<a>`, and the best point to inject that functionality in is during the creation of your `<a>`.

You'll have to add the click handler via a classic bind, and work off from there:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
})
.done(function (m) {
    var link = $('<a>').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    // do whatever else with the link
    link.appendTo('something');
});
```

Comment: This is true, but using `on()` will result in the same problem: delegated events cannot be canceled because they already have been processed at the element level before they bubble up to their delegated target.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ~ that point completely passed over my head. Good catch on bringing that to light. Rewrote my answer.

Comment: I have no the access to the html ot the callback of the ajax, just to add javascript.

Comment: Do you have access to the `$.ajax()` deferred object at least? How will you know when to apply your code / when the AJAX call completes?

Comment: That's going to be a big problem then. Without a handle on the AJAX call, you have no definite way to know when your AJAX call finishes (and consequently, when your `<a>`s get appended to your DOM). At least, none that come to mind right now. You might be able to pull something off with `$.ajaxStart()` but it's use is also clunky, and not recommended even by the jQuery team themselves.

Comment: The "live" function supposed to work. The ajax is not so relevant.

Comment: An event handler set using `live` is a kind of delegated event.